# Is there a plausible pythonic way to get the efforded output with forloops

Tags: python, for-loop, command-line-interface

I need to print those value pairs created in the upper part printed out with the for loop beyond, so that I may add few new vars dynamically as that program will grow...

Print to cli should look like

```
[vargroup] 
Varname:Varvalue
... 
[vargroup1] 
Varname:Varvalue
...
```

I'm now sitting a long time here and trying different things but in most cases it says something about integers and slices, tuples and that the forloop cannot handle listindexes... Im really new to python even to programming and I really do not understand what the interpreter wants from me... now my friend told me that you could help me :Oo

```
import configparser



def test():
#defining Arrays for Settingmanipulation
#default group



    default_rel = []
    default_rel.append('DEFAULT')

#program specific group
#define
    program_rel_name = []
    program_rel_val = []


    program_rel = [program_rel_name, program_rel_val]
    program_rel_name.append("")

#example for a vargroup
program_rel_val.append('OPERATIONAL')       #Name
    program_rel_name.append("FileName")
    program_rel_val.append('settings.ini')      #inifile Name
    program_rel_name.append("WorkDir")
    program_rel_val.append('..')                #workdir

#data related group
    data_rel_name = []
    data_rel_val = []

    data_rel = [data_rel_name, data_rel_val]
    data_rel_name.append("")
    data_rel_val.append ('DATA')  # Name
    data_rel_name.append("aIndex")
    data_rel_val.append ('sp500')  # aindex
    data_rel_name.append("dataSetType")
    data_rel_val.append ('jk')  # dataSet (joined Closes)
    data_rel_name.append("joinData")
    data_rel_val.append('True')         #mData (join those Closes)
    data_rel_name.append("visualizeData")
    data_rel_val.append('True')         #(v )run Visualizer

#maschine learning related
    ml_rel_name = []
    ml_rel_val = []

    ml_rel = [ml_rel_name, ml_rel_val]
    ml_rel_name.append("")
    ml_rel_val.append("MaschineLearning")   #Name
    ml_rel_name.append("runMlPreprocessor")
    ml_rel_val.append('True')               #run ml preprocessor


    inifile = [program_rel, data_rel, ml_rel]



#writing inifile
    config = configparser.ConfigParser ()
    cinfig ={}
    Group=1
    ValuePair=3
#output shall be to cli like demonstrated with this print
    print(inifile[Group][0][ValuePair] + ":"+ inifile[Group][1][ValuePair])
    print()
    print()

#by this forloop
    for count, Groups in enumerate(inifile):
        for counti, ValuePairs in inifile[count]:
            print(inifile[count][0][counti] + ": " + inifile[count][1][counti])



test()
```

on this code, i designed a for loop to print out those value pairs stored in the multidimensional array.... now after 4 hrs on trying to arrange the needed output in a param:value format im hard about giving up...
do you have any idea how to get this done?

Example input is given due to the array is created in this class Output is an error in line 69 which says

```
 for counti, ValuePairs in inifile[count][0]: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Comment: assing `inifile[count][0]` to single variable and uses `print()` to see what you have in variable. Error shows that you have only one value  `inifile[count][0]`  and you can't assign it to two variables.

Comment: always when you have problem first use `print()` to see what you have in variable.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep names and values in separated lists. Better keep it in dictionary - `dict["runMlPreprocessor"] = True` - or atleast as list of tuples - ie. `("runMlPreprocessor", True)`. In current version you would need `zip(names, values)` to get it as pairs.

Comment: when now I look at `for counti, ValuePairs in inifile[count]` then I think maybe you forgot `enumerate()` for this `for counti, ValuePairs in enumerate(inifile[count])` but instead of `inifile[count]` you could use `Groups` - `for counti, ValuePairs in enumerate(Groups)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To print inifile:

Replace:

```
 for count, Groups in enumerate(inifile):
        for counti, ValuePairs in inifile[count]:
            print(inifile[count][0][counti] + ": " + inifile[count][1][counti])
```

With

```
for lst_pair in inifile:
    for i, item in enumerate(lst_pair[0]):
        print('{} : {}'.format(item, lst_pair[1][i]))
```

**Output**

```
 : OPERATIONAL
FileName : settings.ini
WorkDir : ..
 : DATA
aIndex : sp500
dataSetType : jk
joinData : True
visualizeData : True
 : MaschineLearning
runMlPreprocessor : True
```

**Explanation**

inifile contents are:

```
[   [['', 'FileName', 'WorkDir'], ['OPERATIONAL', 'settings.ini', '..']],
    [   ['', 'aIndex', 'dataSetType', 'joinData', 'visualizeData'],
        ['DATA', 'sp500', 'jk', 'True', 'True']],
    [['', 'runMlPreprocessor'], ['MaschineLearning', 'True']]]
```

This is a list of list pairs.

The outer for loop loops through the lists:

```
for lst_pair in inifile:
```

The first list pair for instance is:

```
[['', 'FileName', 'WorkDir'], ['OPERATIONAL', 'settings.ini', '..']],
```

Pairs are:

```
lst_pair[0] = ['', 'FileName', 'WorkDir']
lst_pair[1] = ['OPERATIONAL', 'settings.ini', '..']
```

We loop over lst_pair[0], getting the index and value of each item using:

```
for i, item in enumerate(lst_pair[0]):
```

We match that with the second list using **lst_pair[1][i]**, which is the i-th item in the second list (i.e. lst_pair[1]).

Thus, each item in the first list is paired with an item in the 2nd list using lst_pair[1][i].

We print these pairs using:

```
print('{} : {}'.format(item, lst_pair[1][i]))
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted it looks great. Soon as I Setup my new computer I will try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you made it too complicated using separated lists for names and values and now you have to uses `zip()` to create pair with name with value

```
for all_names, all_values in inifile:
    for name, value in zip(all_names, all_values):
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, value))
```

---

You could make it simpler using tuples `(name, value)`

```
def test():
    default_rel = [
        ('', 'DEFAULT'),
    ]

    program_rel = [
        ("", 'OPERATIONAL'),
        ("FileName", 'settings.ini'),
        ("WorkDir", '..'),
    ]

    data_rel = [
        ("", 'DATA'),
        ("aIndex", 'sp500'),
        ("dataSetType", 'jk'),
        ("joinData", True),
        ("visualizeData", True),
    ]

    ml_rel = [
        ("", "MaschineLearning"),
        ("runMlPreprocessor", True),
    ]

    inifile = [program_rel, data_rel, ml_rel]

    for group in inifile:
        for name, value in group:
            print('{}: {}'.format(name, value))

test()
```